# Listener function for store fires twice on update in grid

Tags: extjs

I have a editable Ext grid panel. The store it uses has a listener that fires a function when a record is changed:

```
listeners:{
    update: someFunction
    },
```

The function changes some values in the store, so the function is fired again.
Is there a way to run the function once?
Maybe to use another listener?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've achieved this by adding

```
store.removeListener('update', someFunction);
```

in the beginning of the function changing the value in the store and:

```
store.addListener('update', someFunction);
```

in the end.

Maybe there is a better way?

Answer (score 2):

Examining the [ExtJS Store documentation](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.data.Store), you may want to look at the `beforesave`event (emphasis mine):

> Fires before a save action is called. A save encompasses **destroying records, updating records and creating records**.

Alternatively you could use...

```
store.addListener('update', someFunction, store, {single: true});
```

...to ensure that the callback function only takes place the next time `update` is called.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue (using Ext JS 4.1). I looked also for two controllers instances issue (might be helpful for someone, is described here: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?179105-Store-loads-amp-duplicates-records-but-API-only-called-once) but after I checked and was sure that I have only one controller instantiated I was looking for another solution.

**nicolasbui** hint works for me perfectly.

Here is my code taken from the Store:

```
listeners: {
    load: function(store, records, success, options) {
        console.log("Store: load event.");
    },
    scope: this,
    single: true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

ExtJS Store has a `suspendEvents` method, which suspends firing of all events, and a `resumeEvents` method, which resumes firing events. I suppose you could use those instead of removing and adding the listener - it would be a bit "cleaner" approach, in my opinion.

Comment: I don't know why, but if I use suspend/resume events the grid is updated only when the event is fired again manually, though I use suspendEvents(false)/

Comment: I resorted to calling 
- `store.suspendEvents()` before expensive actions (like `.set()`) on the store, - `store.resumeEvents()` after the actions are finished and finally 
- `grid.view.refresh()` manually right after resuming store events

Answer (score 1):

I got impresion that source of your double fire is in "The function changes some values in the store".

I guess that in EditGridPanel you are able to edit / change columns A,B,C,D but changes in A,C in handler make changes on "some values" like column E. In your handler (someFunction) make sure that changes coming form A,B,C,D not from E...

I do not know your code and what happend in someFunction -> why it only guess

Answer (score 1):

Any event can be a launch only once as iit will be removed automatically with the boolean option **single** as **true**. Use this to acheive it:

```
// as config
listeners: {
    update: {fn: somefunc, single: true }
}
// with adListener()/on()
cmp.on('update', myFunc, scope, { single: true });
```

And this syntax will work on Ext 3/4

The real solution if you need to update a lot of items and just one event to launch, just use as mentionned **suspendEvents()** to suspend event firing and **resumeEvents()** to cancel the suspension. Just use **fireEvent()** at the end to do the trick.